# Show that multiplication by a Householder matrix does not change the resulting vector's length.

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

Suppose $H$ is an $n$ x $n$ Householder matrix.
Suppose that $w$ and $v$ are $n$-vectors with $w$ = $Hv$.
Assume $v = (v_1,v_2,...,v_n)^T$ and H is generated by a vector $u = (u_1, u_2, ..., u_n)^T$.
Show that $\left\lVert w \right\rVert = \left\lVert v \right\rVert$.

I've been given a hint, but I am not sure if it's required:
For $a = (a_1,a_2,...a_n)^T$ and $b = (b_1,b_2,...,b_n)^T$, $$a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + ... + a_nb_n = a^Tb$$.

So far, I have calculated a few things that I know are true, but I am not sure how to proceed with them.

- $\left\lVert w \right\rVert =\sqrt {w_1^2 + w_2^2 + ... + w_n^2} = \sqrt{w^Tw}$
- $\left\lVert v \right\rVert = \sqrt {v_1^2 + v_2^2 + ... + v_n^2} = \sqrt{v^Tv}$
- $Hv = v - \frac{2u^Tv}{u^Tu}u$
- I also know that $H = H^T = H^{-1}$.

Can anyone get me rolling in the right direction with any of these?

Comment: What’s $Hv\cdot Hv$? Another way to prove this is to observe that $H$ is orthogonally diagonalizable with eigenvalues equal to $\pm1$.

Comment: Is it supposed to end up as just $v^2$? If so, I am having trouble simplifying the equation when I FOIL out the terms, as I'm not getting that.

Comment: $\|Hv\|^2 = (Hv)^T(Hv)=v^T (H^TH)v = v^Tv=\|v\|^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All we have to do is follow the calculation of $|| \vec w ||$.

$|| \vec w || = || H \vec v ||$ since $\vec w = H \vec v$.

Next, we can see that $|| H \vec v || = \sqrt{ (H \vec v)^T (H \vec v) }$ by the definition of the length of a vector.

$(H \vec v)^T = \vec v^T H^T$ since we can distribute the transpose operation, so $\sqrt{ (H \vec v)^T (H \vec v) } = \sqrt { \vec v^T H^T H \vec v }$.

$H^TH = I$ by the properties of a Householder matrix, so $\sqrt { \vec v^T H^T H \vec v } = \sqrt { \vec v^T \vec v }$.

Lastly, $\sqrt { \vec v^T \vec v } = || \vec v ||$ by the definition of the length of a vector, as we used before.

Using all of this together, we can see that $|| \vec w || = || \vec v || $ is in fact true.

$$ || \vec w || = || H \vec v || = \sqrt{ (H \vec v)^T (H \vec v) } = \sqrt { \vec v^T H^T H \vec v } = \sqrt { \vec v^T \vec v } = || \vec v ||$$

Answer (score 2):

We will show $\mathbf{H}$ is orthogonal matrix which implies Householder reflections preserve length.

Define the Householder matrix:
$$
\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{I} - 2\frac{u u^{T}}{u^{T} u}
$$
Show the Householder matrix is orthogonal:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{H} \,\mathbf{H}^{T} &=
%
\left( \mathbf{I} - 2\frac{u u^{T}}{u^{T} u} \right)
%
\left( \mathbf{I} - 2\frac{u u^{T}}{u^{T} u} \right)^{T} \\
%
&=
%
\mathbf{I} - 4\frac{u u^{T}} {u^{T} u} + 4\frac{u \left(u^{T}u\right) u^{T}} {\left(u^{T} u\right)^{2}} \\
%
&= \mathbf{I} - 4\frac{u u^{T}} {u^{T} u} + 4\frac{u u^{T}} {u^{T} u} \\
%
&= \mathbf{I}
%
\end{align}
$$

As noted by @amd, the final step is to show Householder reflections preserve length. For a nonzero vector $x$,
$$
\begin{align}
  \lVert \mathbf{H}\, x \rVert^{2} &=
  \left( \mathbf{H}\, x \right)^{T} \left( \mathbf{H}\, x \right) \\
  &= x^{T} \left(\mathbf{H}^{T} \, \mathbf{H}\right) x \\
  &= x^{T} x.
\end{align}
$$ 
Therefore 
$$
\lVert \mathbf{H}\, x \rVert = \lVert x \rVert
$$

Comment: The OP already knows that $H$ is orthogonal. That’s the last of the bullet points in the question.